# Equality of lists of arbitrarily ordered objects kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, equality

What is the correct way to check the equality of two lists of objects for which the order is irrelevant but repeats are significant, when the objects are not easily sortable (eg they are each of many different types)?

Obviously it is doable by removing equal pairs from each until none match, but this seems inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a group-and-fold operation to efficiently convert each list into a map of items by their counts.

```
fun equalIgnoreOrder(a: List<*>, b: List<*>): Boolean {
    return a.groupingBy { it }.eachCount() == b.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
}
```

Comment: For anyone else reading this, ```groupingBy { it }.eachCount().hashCode()``` can also be used as a matching hashCode

Comment: Hashcodes are not two-way. Two unequal objects can produce the same hash.

Comment: I know? I just meant this would be useful where a hashCode from a list is needed that is equal no matter the order but still has minimal overlap